# onclick not working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click a button "click Me" on my page. I want to know that the button is clicked and an alert should pop up saying hi.Here is my code which is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
     });
if($('#btn').data('clicked')) {
alert("HI");
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btn" value="Click Me" type="button"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `alert` to inside the handler:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    if($(this).data('clicked')) {
        alert("HI");
    }
});
```

That `if` statement doesn't automatically run (well it does on page load since it's in your DOM ready event) - it has to be within an event.

Comment: Actually it will run and be "false", hence no evaluation. I do like your answer.  +1

Comment: Its working but is there any way I can write the alert outside handler.

Comment: @user3885720 -- Why would you want the alert outside the handler?

Comment: @tymeJV- Because I want to add some more code inside if condition.

Comment: @user3885720 -- Then add it - but keep it in the handler if you want it to run everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: What you can do is make an external function and call that if you're afraid of your handler code growing too large.

Comment: @ColinDeClue- I am new to coding. Can you show me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the if statement at all.
It's key to put your alert() call in the click Callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
      alert("HI");
   });
});
```